# Jquery dialog change background inside dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a website and I want to have a book similar dialog. I styled the dialog and all, and now I'm trying to make the dialog change background to an open book when the user clicks a button. The problem is I don't know how I should do that. I've been searching around for a couple of hours now and I haven't come up with anything.

```
.custom_dialog_menu {
    background: url('01_Meny_2.png') !important; 
    border:0px !important;
    width:489px !important;
    height:600px !important;
    position:fixed !important;
}
```

That's my CSS and basically I want the background to change when the user presses the `<div class="forward_button"></div>` (Which is an image).

```
$( "#meny_dialog0" ).dialog({ 
    dialogClass:'custom_dialog_menu',                      
    resizable: false, 
    draggable: false, 
    modal: false,               
    autoOpen: false, 
});

$( ".menu_text" ).click(function() {
  $( "#meny_dialog0" ).dialog( "open" );
  $(".div0").show();
});

$(".forward_button").click(function () {                             
$("meny_dialog0").removeClass('custom_dialog_menu').addClass('custom_dialog_menu_open');

            });
```

This is the dialog initializer and opener and click method.

EDIT: I knew it was something I forgot, so here is the click method...

I put my hope in you guys now, I have no idea how to fix this. I've tried css, remove and add classes and all of that but without any luck.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FusionSausage/a9Y6V/2/

Thanks!

Comment: I think if you show your `click()` method and maybe one of your attempts at `addClass()` it would help.

Comment: I knew it was something I forgot, but it's there now :)

Comment: can you create fiddle for that?

Comment: Here; http://jsfiddle.net/FusionSausage/a9Y6V/2/
I hope that was ok, never done a fiddle before so...